# Quelle serait une bonne façon de formuler une demande sur un chat en ligne?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Je cherche une meilleure énonciation que: Bonjour, j’aimerais avoir des éclaircissements sur la charte des grandeurs utilisée pour l’achat d’un bicycle. Quelle serait une manière courtoise et originale d’entamer la conversation avec un agent du service à la clientèle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vous pourriez par exemple dire:

Bonjour, je me permets de vous contacter car j'aurais besoin d'informations complémentaires.
J’aimerais avoir des éclaircissements sur la charte des grandeurs utilisée pour l’achat d’un **vélo**.

PS: Par contre, je ne sais pas du tout ce que vous entendez par "la charte des grandeurs"  Guide des tailles? ou tout simplement "J’aimerais avoir des éclaircissements sur le choix de la bonne taille pour l’achat d’un vélo.

Comment: *Charte des grandeurs* est un anglicisme québécois (*size chart*) correspondant effectivement ici à un *guide des tailles*, d'autre part *bicycle* est encore utilisable au Québec alors qu'il n'est plus d'usage ici.